# How to update records in an ember model

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, ember-data

I'm fetching a list of records from `App.Resource.find()` This is working fine.

For each row of data there is a drop down box with fixed values. When a change is made to a drop down box I'd like to issue a `POST` or `PUT` request back to the server to update that row with the newly selected value from the drop down.

I am having trouble with two things:

- How can I get the `ID` and selected `value` of the dropdown in my model or controller
- How can I take those values and issue a request to the server. Is there `App.Resource.update...`?

I have a jsBin of the working example with local data: http://jsbin.com/OcAyoYo/84/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's one approach to get the selected value, let's put things where they should go, ok, first of all, let's create a controller which is going to decorate your Response records, you mixed names, you're using Post, so, I'll use that name, here is the controller:

```
App.PostController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  selectedChanged: function() {
    //here, you have access to the selected value with this:
    // this.get('selected')

    //And also, this controller represents you object rendered on the screen,
    //so, you can change it here if you want like this:
    //this.set('whataverPropertyYouWantToChange', 'newValue');

    //then you can save this record(send the request to the server) by just doing this:
    //this.save(); this will make a request to the server
  }.observes('selected')
});
```

then, in order to use that controller, change the loop where you render the records, to this:

```
{{#each model itemController="post"}}
  <tr>
    <td>{{author}}</td>
    <td>{{book}}</td>
    <td>
      {{view Ember.Select
        contentBinding= 'App.names.content'
        selectionBinding='selected'}}
    </td>
  </tr>
{{/each}}
```

just be careful, in PostController, the observer will be fired even if the 'selected' property has null values, you need to verify if it is not null.

Comment: I tried this approach but it isn't working. For example I'm alerting `this.get("selected)` from the controller but it does not  do anything. Infact, I think it does not even get triggered when I make a selection to the drop down box. Example here: http://jsbin.com/OcAyoYo/107/edit

Comment: you didn't do what I said, you didn't create the PostController, you're still using PostsController, and if you check the 'each' loop, I specified itemController="post"

Comment: but if you do not want to create a new controller, you can still use your PostsController, but change the name, it does not mach the rout, it should be PostsAllController, and instead of observing 'selected', you would need to observe '@each.selected'

Comment: this is the one using a new controller http://jsbin.com/ODij/1/ and this is the one using PostsAllController http://jsbin.com/UgaxI/1/

Comment: can I get the row id of the row on which the drop down was clicked as well? My model has an ID field so each row has a unique ID associated to it.

Comment: I think you need to go through a starting guide, like the one in emberjs.com, one of the options I gave you, was to create a new controller PostController, which represents each of your records, so, when you change the action of one of your records, the oberver will be fired, and there you have the record that changed, you don't have the other one, but you are using the PostsAllController, which its content is the array of models, you can loop through it this.get('content').forEach(function(yourmodel) {}) and there you have each of your records. hope it helps

Comment: I understand that concept and the option you presented. I am now using PostController to alert out the value the user selected from the drop down. However, in addition to the selected value, I would also like to show the `ID` of the row that the user clicked at. I can't figure out how to show that ID. I've tried `this.get(selected).id` to no avail

Comment: the id of what ? the html component ? or the id of the record ? if you're trying to get the ID of the record, then, it is easy, just do this.get('id'), at that point PostController is a decorator for your model, so, it already knows your model, you can access whatever property from your model you want.

Comment: ahh ok. didn't know that. Thats the id I was looking for. thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36213/discussion-between-anthony-and-user2506819)